Should we understand the "public reading" mandate of 1 Timothy 4:13 to be inclusive of NT writings?
On the assumption that 1 Timothy was written sometime in the mid-50s to mid-60s,1 then should we understand the "public reading" mandate of 1 Timothy 4:13 to be inclusive of NT writings? Most scholars would acknowledge that a fair number of NT writings would already be available by this time, including most of Paul's writings (on the assumption that they're "authentic"), James, and perhaps a Gospel or three.2

13 Until I come, give attention to the public reading of Scripture, to exhortation and teaching. (1 Timothy 4:13 NASB95)

The immediate context is concerned (1) with teaching Christian principles regarding marriage and foods (1 Tim. 4:3–4), (2) with being a good servant of Christ (4:6), (3) with fixing "our hope on the living God, who is Savior of ... believers (4:10), etc. Hence, it would seem like reading, exhorting, and teaching (1 Tim. 4:13) from authoritative NT writings would be more pertinent than OT writings. And given the near-context to the "Scripture says" passage in 1 Timothy 5:18, this suggests that the texts being read are already considered Scripture, yes?
1 D. A Carson and Douglas J. Moo, An Introduction to the New Testament, 2nd ed. (Grand Rapids, MI: Zondervan, 2005), 572.
2 It remains my contention that Matthew was published coincident with the events in Acts 10/11, per my approach to Irenaeus, and Mark shortly thereafter—refer to this post. However, the above question remains pertinent even if this contention is not accepted.

Questions are far more useful if they contain explicit quotations rather than simply citations.

"… rather than Jewish practices (for example, abstaining from certain foods is not required required per 1 Tim. 4:3–4" is a misinterpretation. In context, 4:1–3 says:
"… in the last times some will turn away from the true faith; they will follow deceptive spirits and teachings that come from demons.
They will say it is wrong … to eat certain foods.
But God created those foods to be eaten with thanks by faithful people who know the truth." (NLT).
Paul is warning about Ascetics, who will try to convince Christians to avoid physical pleasure, to become Vegetarians.

Thanks. Added a quote of the verse and removed the source of the food restrictions.

As far as the time in question goes there is little indication that the letters of Paul were considered scripture yet at the time. The first historical mention of a collection of Paul’s letters being considered scripture is found in the Muratorian Canon (165-185 A.D.). Certainly, since the OP presumes an early date for Timothy (including the idea that it is authentically Pauline), it would seem strange for Paul himself to instruct Timothy to read his own letters as scripture. In fact, no other biblical writer, not even Moses, refers to his own writings as scripture.
In the letters to Timothy as well as the NT generally, the word "scripture" refers to what Christians call the "Old Testament." On the other hand, there is nothing to prevent us today to include the entire corpus of NT in the mandate of 1 Timothy 4:13 regarding the public reading of scripture.

"Little indication" other than that his writings were being treated as authoritative for Christians and were referred to in the NT and in early Christian writings in the same manner as the OT writings? 2 Peter 3:16, in the context of 2 Peter 1:20, seems pretty clearly to be describing Paul's writings as prophetically inspired Scripture. Likewise, 1 Timothy 5:18 puts the NT writings on a par with OT writings. Or are you contending that prophetic writings must be canonized by some subsequent authoritative body to be considered Scripture?

I've equated 1st Tim. 4:13 to 1st Cor. 14.  This involves where one of the gifts of the Holy Spirit, was speaking in tongues. The main point Paul was making was the edification of the Church. That speaking in tongues was useful in some situations but speaking from the scriptures or that which the Holy Spirit gave them was for more important when one would hear it in their own language without interpreters.
In Tim. 4:13 it is obvious that Timothy was to do just that.  Read the scripture when they came together, straight forward, so that the body of believers would be blessed.  Notice in verse 12 of 1st Timothy all of the things that Paul had listed in 1st Cor. is in 1st. Tim. 4.
There are a multitude of reasons that state that scripture reading must be part of the services or whenever discussing the word of God.
A short answer is yes it must be done.

Answers are far more useful if they contain explicit quotations rather than simply citations.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.
